# Does a Toast in postDelayed leak the activity?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I got a comment from a colleague, he said that if I do:

```
    ...onClick() {
    final Context context = MyActivity.this;
    ....postDelayed(new Runnable() { ...
          Toast.makeText(context, R.string.hello, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    ...
```

then my activity is leaked if the post happens after the activity is destroyed.

How should I avoid this ?

Comment: yes if your second param to `postDelayed` is something like 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By creating an anonymous `Runnable` class within an `Activity` you are creating an implicit reference to your outer class, thereby leaking the context of the activity. 
Your delayed toast message will continue in the main thread message queue preventing a garbage collect of your activity context.

Use a static handler with a weak reference to your activity context (Static inner classes do not hold an implicit reference to their outer class).

```
private final ToastHandler mHandler = new ToastHandler(this);

private static class ToastHandler extends Handler {
    private final WeakReference<MainActivity> mActivity;

    public ToastHandler(MainActivity activity) {
        mActivity = new WeakReference<>(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        MainActivity activity = mActivity.get();
        Bundle data = msg.getData();
        if (activity != null) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, data.getString("TEST_KEY"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}


  private static final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() { 
                    Message message = new Message();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("TEST_KEY", "TEST");
                    message.setData(bundle);
                    mHandler.handleMessage(message);
      }
  };
```

In your onClick...

```
 mHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
```

Edit: Oops, your runnable needs to be static ofc

Comment: Thanks but how do I pass in data to runnable in my onClick ?

Comment: I guess you will never know